# C3P0 connections' health checks

Tags: database, connection, c3p0, pool

I hope there is some expert on C3P0 that can help me answer the following question.

First, here's the general problem I'm trying to solve. We have an application connected to a database. When the database goes out, requests start taking several seconds to be processed, as opposed to a few milliseconds. This is because C3P0 will attempt to create new connections to the database. It will eventually timeout and the request will be rejected.

I came up with a proposal to fix it. Before grabbing a connection from the pool, I'll query C3P0's APIs to see if there are any connections in the pool. If there are none, we'll immediately drop the request. This way, our latency should remain in the milliseconds, instead of waiting until the timeout occurs. This solution works because C3P0 is capable of removing connections if it detects that they've gone bad.

Now, I set up a test with the values for "setTestConnectionOnCheckin" and "setTestConnectionOnCheckout" as "false". According to my understanding, this would mean that C3P0 would not test a connection (or, let's say, a connection in use, because there's also the idleConnectionTestPeriod setting). However, when I run my test, immediately after shutting off the database, C3P0 detects it and removes the connections from the pool. To give you a clearer picture, here's the execution's result:

14:48:01 - Request processed successfully. Processing time: 5 ms.
14:48:02 - Request processed successfully. Processing time: 4 ms.
14:48:03 - (Database is shut down at this point).
14:48:04 - java.net.ConnectException.
14:48:05 - Request rejected. Processing time: 258 ms.
14:48:06 - Request rejected. Processing time: 1 ms.
14:48:07 - Request rejected. Processing time: 1 ms.

C3P0 apparently knew that the database went down and removed the connections from the pool. It probably took a while, because the very first request after the database was shut off took longer than the others. I have run this test several times and that single request can take from 1 ms up to 3.5 seconds (which is the timeout time). This entry appears as many times as the number of connections I have defined for my pool. I have omitted all the rest for simplicity.

I think it's great that C3P0 is capable of removing the connections from the pool right away (well, as quickly as 258 ms. in the above example), but I'm having troubles explaining other people why that works. If "setTestConnectionOnCheckin" and "setTestConnectionOnCheckout" are set to "false", how is C3P0 capable of knowing that a connection went bad?

Even if they were set to "true", testing a connection is supposed to attempt executing a query on the database (something like "select 1 + 1 from dual"). We the database goes down, shouldn't the test timeout? In other words, shouldn't C3P0 take 3.5 seconds to determine that a connection has gone bad?

Thanks a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(apologies... this'll be terse, i'm phonebound.)

1) even if no explicit Connection testing has been configured, c3p0 tests Connections that experience Exceptions while checked-out to determine whether they remain suitable for pooling.

2) a good JDBC driver will throw Exceptions quickly if the DBMS is unavailable. there's no reason why these internal Connection tests should be slow.

3) rather than polling for unused Connections to avoid waiting for checking / new acquisitions, you might consider just setting the config parameter checkoutTimeout.

good luck!